# How to Create Fire Reflection in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection, fire

I'm making a fireplace.

The Eevee rendered image has no fire reflection when using a Principled Volume shader on both stainless steel and glass surface.

I tried using a Reflection Cubemap to no avail.

[image]

Comment: You should have a reflection (unless there's a limitation with Principled Volume?) but anyway it won't be animated, so maybe you should fake reflections with some lights?

Comment: Thank you, adding light is a good idea!